# C++ method that takes N parameters

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector, parameters, variadic-functions

Saying that I have my **A** class with **foo(...)** method where:

> **...** => stands for a variable number of parameters

I want to save all this parameters on a std::vector.

I've try with:

```
std::vector<std::string> A::foo(...) {
  std::vector<std::string> list;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, 0); 
  for ( ; /* which condition to exit? */ ; ) {
      std::string s = va_arg(args, char*);
      list.push_back(s);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Obviously this can't works, but I can't figure out how can I fill **s** string and understand when exit from cicle.

In main I will call foo in this way:

```
foo("param0", "param1", "param2", ... , "paramN")
```

Comment: You assume all the parameters are the same type. Why not pass an array of strings?

Comment: Because I want a code "elastic".. who will use foo, in my mind, should not make the effort to create an array and then pass it to foo..

Comment: I prefer inelastic code that is safe. They can call as `foo({ "param0", "param1", "param2", ... , "paramN"});`

Comment: If your arguments are not constrained to be strings, then I would suggest your function return `std::vector<void*>`. I think that is more consistent with not knowing the argument types in advance.

Comment: @NeilKirk and then foo how works?

Comment: @Logicrat when I have foo working for string I could think to extend to void*, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what foo is doing. If it just packages the parameters into an array and returns it, then it's a useless function, at least in C++11.

Comment: foo takes N string and return vector<string>. Don't worry about how I use it! (:

Comment: If you are using C++11, you can just use the code `vector<string> v = { "one", "two"};`

Comment: Make the calling convention be that the last argument must be 0.

Answer (score 2):

You should somehow pass to the function count of arguments. For example look at `int printf ( const char * format, ... );`. The function parses format string and determines how many arguments have been provided. You can change your code to something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> A::foo(size_t count, ...) {
  std::vector<std::string> list;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, 0); 
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
      std::string s = va_arg(args, char*);
      list.push_back(s);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to write `A::foo` is to write it as a C++11 variadic template:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::vector<std::string> A::foo(Args&& ...args) {
    return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

If this isn't an option, you can accept *up to* a fixed number of arguments using default arguments:

```
std::vector<std::string> A::foo(
    const char* arg1 = 0,
    const char* arg2 = 0,
    // ...
    const char* arg10 = 0)
{
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    if (arg1) ret.push_back(arg1); else return ret;
    if (arg2) ret.push_back(arg2); else return ret;
    // ...
    if (arg10) ret.push_back(arg10); else return ret;
    return ret;
}
```

You can use a preprocessing library e.g. [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) to automate generation of the repeated parameters and parameter handlers.

Comment: Excellent answer. 1+.